# File read lines blue screen windows

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7

What problem in this code?? It crash my windows after two or tree executions.

```
import os

f = file("C:\test.txt", "r")

try: 
    for l in f.readlines():
        if l <> "":
            print l
except:
    pass
finally:
    f.close()
```

> Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your system, not the code.

Comment: @Wooble blue screen does not appear long time. I see run this code five blue screens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably when using the "import os" while at windows. Long ago I tried to deal with making folders using python at windows and i used that library, but I was told that it could crash my windows. Try using any diferente library than the os, there are a few other options.